# detcting speed of object via camera in ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera

I'm looking to point my phone at a moving object and have the phone estimate the velocity of the object. Is there an way for that?

Uses:
- speed of baseball pitch
- speed of car
- speed of pinewood derby car

any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Perhaps you could take a video of the moving object from the side. Knowing the distance the camera is from the object, as well as the distance the object has moved between successive frames should allow you to calculate the object's velocity for a known frame rate. Depending on object/background it may be possible to do this with some image processing techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question and idea.

Firstly, unless the object is moving straight towards you, I suspect its impossible. I suspect it is not practical even if it is moving straight towards you.

You can estimate speed by distance over time. On iOS and Android I think you can get access to the distance calculated by the autofocus, but is probably too slow and inaccurate for any practical purpose.

If you are in reasonably quiet environment it may be possible to use much the same technique as radar speed cameras but using sound. If you bounce a sound off a moving target then the frequency is changed according to the speed of the object (Doppler effect). Your phone would emit a very loud fixed frequency for a fraction of a second. The sound bounces off the object and is frequency shifted. Your phone picks up the sound from the microphone, filters out the source signal, and looks for the shifted signal. You would need to be somewhere quiet and measuring something that reflects sound well (like a derby car, and unlike a baseball).

Failing this, I would attach your phone to the object and use a GPS tracker. Not so good for a baseball, I will admit.